# How to setup a development server on Linux?

Tags: 7

I am developing a new web site for a client who is already on the web with an old site.

I need to develop the site under a different name (dns) and when it's ready, move it safely to a right name.

I am developing and hosting on AWS under Ubuntu using multi-site setup.

When I am ready I will pointing the DNS to my development server and by doing so I will be on air with the real site.
My question is: While developing I will be directing another domain to the development server say something like deveopment.com by the time I am ready to go live, I will be pointing the real domain to it, say real.com
Other than the dns' what else will I have to change on the server?
Will I have to change anything in the DB? Remember it’s on the same server and I can use the same DB.

Am I likely to run into any trouble?

Comment: If your development server becomes the live (production) server itself, please take extra care for security considerations (eg other vhosts that may operate on dev, other services that run, OS updates etc.). Often dev servers tend to be more "relaxed" securiy-wise.

Answer (score 2):

It should work with no or limited changes. However, some modules include fully qualified paths in database tables or variables, so it is worth checking.

Some areas to look at are:

- `settings.php`, particularly the database array, `$cookie_domain`, and `$base_url`
- The sites directory: are you using the `default` directory or one tied to your development environment? If your material is in `sites/my.dev.com` then you'll have `my.dev.com` in the files table
- URL related modules like `securepages`, `xmlsitemap`, and so on

When I am moving from dev to production, I also use `drush` to double-check that I missed nothing. Running `drush vget` dumps the content of the variables table, so I can grep that for URLs. For example to see all the variables that have `www.indiemade.com` hardcoded:

```
$ drush vget | grep indiemade
securepages_basepath: 'http://www.indiemade.com'
securepages_basepath_ssl: 'https://www.indiemade.com'
seotools_base_url: 'https://www.indiemade.com'
xmlsitemap_base_url: 'http://www.indiemade.com'
...
```

One other tool you might want to look into is drush migrate, well explained [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-and-sync-drupal-sites-with-drush).

Answer (score 1):

Normally not. If you are not using any special, domain related, modules (Mike domain access for example) you should be fine. Of course it is always a good idea to test it first(for example with a subdomain) to see  how the  site behaves on a new domain.